# iOS 7 background upload and POST requests

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-upload, ios7, nsurlsession

I need to upload files in the background with other HTTP **POST** requests before and after each upload.

Previously I was using **beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler** which was working perfectly till iOS 6 but from IOS 7 it is restricted for approx 180 seconds only which is a concern.

I have read the documents regarding NSURLSession were in we have Background transfer service. But the problem with this is it only allows upload and download in background. It doesn't allow me to make POST request after every upload in the background.

So is there any way to make the POST request along with the background uploads?

Any hint in the right direction would  be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use NSURLSessionDownloadTask to send a POST.

IMO, download task doesn't mean it is used for download. it means the response of your POST request (json/xml) will be downloaded to a local file. Then you can open that file and parse it to get the request.

if you want you can even use a NSURLSessionDownloadTask to upload files to S3. and the s3 response will be 'downloaded' to a local file..

for more information, see this question in the apple developer forum https://devforums.apple.com/thread/210515?tstart=0

Answer (score 3):

I successfully round-trip a vanilla `http` call during a background task's callback, in production code. The [callback](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionTaskDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLSessionTaskDelegate/URLSession%3atask%3adidCompleteWithError%3a) is:

```
-[id<NSURLSessionTaskDelegate> URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:]
```

You get about 30 seconds there to do what you need to do. *Any* async calls made during that time must be bracketed by

```
-[UIApplication beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler:]
```

and the "end task" version of [that](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginBackgroundTaskWithName%3aexpirationHandler%3a). Otherwise, iOS will kill your process when you pop the stack (while you are waiting for your async process).

BTW, don't confuse `UIApplication` tasks (I call them "app tasks") and `NSURLSession` tasks ("session tasks").

Comment: Unfortunately creating background tasks when the app was launched by the background transfer's delegate doesn't increase your 30 seconds window

Comment: No, but each task has a callback which gives you another time increment, during which you can queue more tasks. Thus you can chain an indefinite number of tasks together. I have this running in production, and can, say, upload 1000 photos entirely in the background.

Comment: @Clay Haven't tested that but sounds genius. can you put some source code? Thanks.

Comment: @Sasho I have, in bits and pieces. Maybe I'll put something complete on github someday. Meanwhile, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A45813+%5Bnsurlsession%5D) is every NSURLSession answer I've made.

Comment: Clay Bridges Could you please explain to me how you managed this? does it work with Amazon S3 as well?

Comment: @Xcoder: **Answer #1**: I found it devilishly tricky. [My Q&A here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A45813+%5Bnsurlsession%5D) is the most accessible form so far of what I know about it. **Answer #2**: we're doing this with S3.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `uploadTaskWithRequest:fromData:completionHandler:` you can make your HTTP POST request from the completion handler block:

```
[backgroundSession uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:data completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
    if (httpResponse.statusCode == 200) {
        NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://somethingorother.com/"]];
        request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
        .
        .
        .
        NSURLResponse *postResponse;
        NSError *postError;
        NSData *postResponseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:postRequest returningResponse:&postResponse error:&postError]; 
        // Check postResponse and postError to ensure that the POST succeeded
    }
}];
```

Comment: this is only valid for foreground calls. For background task we have to use delegates only